# Selenium xPath: Invalid selector -- When passing multiple condition for the same element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the XPath expression:

```
//span[@class='title-subGrid-lite-TextAutoEllipsis’][text()[contains(.,'My Emails')]
```

Correct me.

Comment: post some sample input please?

Comment: `//span[@class='title-subGrid-lite-TextAutoEllipsis' and contains(.,'My Emails')]` are tou looking for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //span[@class='title-subGrid-lite-TextAutoEllipsis’][text()[contains(.,'My Emails')]
```

...implies that the *XPath* which you have used was not a valid one.

The *xpath* expression you have used as follows have a couple of issues:

```
//span[@class='title-subGrid-lite-TextAutoEllipsis’][text()[contains(.,'My Emails')]
```

- The *class* attribute needs to be properly placed in-between single quotes i.e. `'...'`.
- The *text* attribute needs to be properly placed in-between `[...]`

The simple *XPath* expression which must have catered to your requirement is:

```
//span[@class='title-subGrid-lite-TextAutoEllipsis'][contains(.,'My Emails')]
```

As an alternative you can also try:

```
//span[@class='title-subGrid-lite-TextAutoEllipsis' and contains(.,'My Emails')]
```

Perhaps you must be looking for:

```
//span[@class='title-subGrid-lite-TextAutoEllipsis'][normalize-space()='My Emails']
```